# Spring JMS - Delay processing of messages in MessageListener class

Tags: spring, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms, websphere-8

My application is running on WAS 8.5 & consumes messages from IBM MQ 9 using the JMS MessageListener. When my application starts initially, there is also a cache being formed by accessing the data from DB. However, if any restart or stop/start of JVMs are done, my application goes into a null pointer state as the cache is not fully loaded & the onMessage method starts picking up messages from MQ. The cache is used by Spring for dependency injection. In this scenario, how can I stop or how can the MessageListener class wait until the cache is fully loaded. Below is the code snippet of my MessageListener as well LoadCache class.

**JMS Message Listener**

```
public class MQMessageConsumer implements MessageListener {
    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MQMessageConsumer.class);

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(500);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        log.debug("There is a message in the Queue");
        String inputXML = null;

        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            try {
                inputXML = ((TextMessage) message).getText();

                MQMessageProcessor mqp = new MQMessageProcessor(inputXML);
                executor.submit(mqp);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Error in processing the message - " + e.getMessage());
            }
        } else
            log.error("Invalid message format, please resend with correct MQ message header as MQSTR");

    }
}
```

**LoadCache**

```
public class LoadCache implements ServletContextListener{

    private Cache cache;
    protected static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(LoadCache.class);
    private ApplicationService service = new ApplicationService();

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event){
        cache = Cache.getCache();
        try {
            System.out.println("Cache building started during strtup");
            /*log.debug("Cahe building started during strtup");*/
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            loadProperties(cache);
            loadDataTable(cache);
            loadOP(cache);
            loadUCM(cache);
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() ;
            System.out.println("Total Cache building time is :"+(endTime - startTime));
            /*log.debug("Total Cache building time is :"+(endTime - startTime));*/
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.debug("Error While communicating to database:"+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event){
        System.out.println("Context Destroyed-LoadCache Gone");
    }

}
```

How can I make my application listener wait till the cache is loaded? I also tried creating a default constructor in the MessageConsumer class & added a Thread sleep of 20 seconds but that did not help aas well. Any fix as to how this can be achieved?

Comment: My knowledge on Spring JMS is minimal. However, can you check if you have a connection.start() method call in your code? If yes, ensure that connection.start() is called after your cache is fully initialized. Calling connection.start() tells the queue manager to start the delivery of messages.

Comment: Are you using a [DefaultMessageListenerContainer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html)? Then I would turn `LoadCache` into a bean which initialises in the constructor and make this bean a dependency of the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`.

Comment: @DanielSteinmann I am currently using JMS listener container. However I can try this approach of using a ```DefaultMessageListenerContainer```.